# Expression « Enfin moi je dis ça, je dis rien »

Tags: expressions, sens

J'ai souvent entendu l'expression suivante : « enfin moi je dis ça, je dis rien ».

Que veut-elle dire exactement ? D’où vient cette expression ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cette expression est assez récente, je la retrouve souvent sur Twitter sous la forme du <s>mot-dièse</s> hashtag #jdcjdr. Elle ressemble à l'*infamous* « à mon humble avis », on la rencontre essentiellement dans deux sens :

1. dans le même ordre d'idée que « *no offence meant* » ou « *just saying* » elle peut servir à atténuer la gravité d'un reproche ou d'une critique négative¹ en précisant qu'on ne veut pas imposer son point de vue

   > Moi j'aurais pas mis une bannière violette sur un fond rayé jaune et vert, enfin, je dis ça, je dis rien.
2. en général, elle s'emploie plutôt par inversion du sens 1 pour ajouter une pincée de sarcasme à une critique ou à une observation

   > Là c'est franchement immonde, on dirait que  quelqu'un a vomi sur le parchemin, enfin, je dis ça, je dis rien, mais c'est atroce

Pour l'origine historique je cherche encore, l'intelligence collective du web penche pour une réplique d'un film de la troupe du Splendid, mais je n'ai pas de preuves.

La construction ressemble à celle de « je ne suis pas raciste/sexiste/[bubalocaseiphobe](http://www.cledut.net/xylo.htm)/… mais je n'aime pas la mozzarella », à savoir qu'en affirmant qu'on ne fait pas offense on atténue la gravité de le faire quand même. C'est un procédé classique qui a même sûrement un nom pédant et une bibliographie.

---

¹ Goffman aurait parlé de préservation de [face](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_%28Erving_Goffman%29).

Comment: Ok pour le sens. Cependant, d'où vient l'expression ?

Comment: Tout comme Evpok, je penche aussi sur un des films du S¡plendid, mais sans en avoir ni en trouver la preuve formelle...

Comment: L'intelligence collective du web penche aussi pour **Coluche** dans **Ciao Pantin** comme origine. Mais là encore, aucune preuve... voir un indice à http://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080715123758AApRVtY (... tiens, et quelle est l'origine de "ciao" ? )

Comment: @Evpok Cela semble être une forme de litote http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litote, à moins que d'académiques sapiences ne donnent une définition plus ciblée.

Answer (score 2):

"Je dis ça, je dis rien", il me semble que c'est de la [prétérition](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pr%C3%A9t%C3%A9rition): une figure de style par laquelle on attire l'attention sur une chose en déclarant n'en pas parler.

Comment: Cela y ressemble beaucoup … il est loin d'être certain que l'usager actuel de cette tournure de style en connaisse le nom … loin de témoigner de la finesse d'une discussion, elle en signe que : « On ne dira pas qu'il faut être débile pour utiliser cette tournure …  puisque ce n'est qu'un tic de langage [sous-entendu : *mais*  « Ne pas savoir se taire plutôt que de dire des inepties, d'après vous, c'est crétin ou idiot ?] »